# How to count vowels in a string?

Tags: java, string, count

The objective is to count how many vowels there are in the phrase that the user inputs.
The user will input a phrase which will be

```
my name is nic
```

The output will be for this example is

```
Vowel Count: 4
```

Now here is my code.

```
    import cs1.Keyboard;
public class VowelCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter in a sentence.");
            String phrase = Keyboard.readString();
            char[] phraseArray = phrase.toCharArray();
            char[] vowels = new char[4];
            vowels[0] = 'a';
            vowels[1] = 'e';
            vowels[2] = 'i';
            vowels[3] = 'o';
            vowels[4] = 'u';
            int vCount = countVowel(phrase, phraseArray, vowels);
            System.out.println("Vowel Count: " + vCount);
    }

    public static int countVowel(String word, char[] pArray, char[] v) {
        int vowelCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (v[i] == pArray[i])
                vowelCount++;
        }
        return vowelCount;
    }
}
```

With my code I am getting an ArrayIndex Error. I know the fix but when I change

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

It fixes the error but does not count the vowels. It outputs

```
Vowel Count: 0
```

So how can I fix this problem and is there a better way to do this than the way I am attempting to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use regular expression. will save you a lot of time

```
int count = word.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]","").length();
```

Comment: is the "^" suppose to be there?

Comment: @NicLaQuatra Yes. the symbol `^` means `'not'`

Comment: Sweet! Also is there anything suppose to go between the empty "" ? Does it mean anything as well?

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to store five vowels in a four vowel array;

```
char[] vowels = new char[5]; // not 4.
vowels[0] = 'a'; // 1
vowels[1] = 'e'; // 2
vowels[2] = 'i'; // 3
vowels[3] = 'o'; // 4
vowels[4] = 'u'; // 5
```

Or,

```
char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

Also, don't forget to call `toLowerCase()` or you'll only count lower case vowels.

Finally, you should be looping over each character in `pArray` and each `vowel`. I'd use two [`for-each` loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
for (char ch : pArray) {
  for (vowel : v) {
    if (ch == v) vowelCount++;
  }
}
```

Comment: All your information is very helpful except the last part with the for loop. I have not learned the for-each loop yet lol